# Stripe: How to list pending webhooks?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

Looking at my server logs I can see some webhooks resulted in a request timeout.

But the logs don't specify what kind of webhook for which customer (customer.subscription.deleted, customer.payment.success, etc.)

I can click each customer in the Stripe dashboard and scroll down to see if a webhook failed, but that's absurdly inefficient.

Anyone knows a clean way of listing pending webhooks, either programmatically or in the dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering Webhook delivery status by pending/failed is available in the Dashboard > Developer > Events > top-left Filter menu.

Direct url: https://dashboard.stripe.com/events?delivery_success=false

[image: Screenshot of Filter menu]

Answer (score 0):

So the best I found is going to the dashboard -> Developers -> Events

If an event has a pending webhook, an icon will indicate so.

[image: pending webhook logo thingy]

After chatting with support though, I can confirm that there is no way to filter down events to only those with pending webhooks, a feature request has been made.

There's most certainly a way to make your own home made solution with the API, but for my current needs the list of events is enough.